# Facebook comments returns 0 for my list of articles

Tags: facebook

I am developing a site like producthunt. I am looking to tap into using Facebook comments widget for the commenting part.

In my homepage, I have a list of posts (showing summary), I would like to display the # of facebook comments for each post.

I am using the following code

```
<span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="http://example.com/"></span> awesome comments
```

where http://example.com/ is the permalink of each of my post.

However, they are all displaying zeros.

Comment: And that permalink URL is the exact(!) same one you used in the comment plugin?

Comment: Yes. It is the exact. Will it be due to i am looping it?  I passed different permalinks in the data-href

Comment: Do you have this “live” already, so that the FB scraper can properly read the URLs and their OG meta data?

Comment: Its at localhost. Is this the reason why?

Comment: To try out. I am using example.com as used in fb example. It shows 0 too.

Comment: Yes, you need to use publicly reachable URLs for this to work properly.